# Adding additional memory in HP server

Tags: memory, hp, hp-proliant

I am planning the installation of additional memory in a HP DL360 server.

Currently, this server has two processors and 8 x 8GB stick of RAM. I have not got access to the server yet so I will assume this is balanced across the two processors.

We are adding another 16GB of RAM. I have been given a 16GB RAM module but Was expecting 2 x 8GB modules.

What would be the recommend way to add this. Should I take 2 of the 8GB sticks from processor 1 and move them to processor 2, and then install the 16GB stick in processor 1?

Comment: Give the stick back and tell the purchaser to do their homework first. I bet they didn't even check whether or not you need an FB-DIMM instead of a regular DIMM, or whether you need ECC vs non-ECC (ECC may not be as important as we all once thought, but you really don't want to mix the two types).

Comment: Also, if you want to balance the ram between processors, you'd only need to move _one_ 8GB stick, not two. But we need to know what generation DL360. That will make a **huge** difference here. And once you know this, the thing to do will be to lookup the manual on HP's web site, which will have some _very specific information_ about _exactly_ where to put what kind of RAM sticks and in what order.

Comment: We'd need to know EXACTLY which DL360 you have, there's loads of versions/generations and they each do memory differently.

Answer (score 2):

I hate when people don't provide all relevant details.

Let's assume the server is a DL360 G6 or G7. If that's the case, there are specific DIMM population guidelines for those models.

If you have ILO access to the server or even the specific model or a way into the existing operating system, you could see the layout and options.

But really, use RAM that's identical to what you have. Return the 16GB module and substitute it with 8GB DIMMs that are similar to what currently in the server.

Comment: If you hate it when people on't provide the relevant details why don't you downvote it ? Don't worry I id it for you.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Joel.  Return the single dimm and order your own after you lookup exactly what is needed.  Meaning no your idea will not work.  You need to physically balance the number of modules between the two procs.